# How to select rows given a list of tuples with a PySpark DataFrame?

Tags: pyspark

Let's say we have a `DataFrame` like this:

```python
+--------+--------------+-----+--------------------+
|aid     |bid           |value|                time|
+--------+--------------+-----+--------------------+
|       1|             1| 81.0|2006-08-25 14:13:...|
|       1|             1| 81.0|2006-08-25 14:27:...|
|       1|             2| 81.0|2006-08-25 14:56:...|
|       1|             2| 81.0|2006-08-25 15:00:...|
|       1|             3| 81.0|2006-08-25 15:31:...|
|       1|             3| 81.0|2006-08-25 15:38:...|
|       1|             4|  0.0|2006-08-30 11:59:...|
|       1|             4|  0.0|2006-08-30 13:59:...|
|       2|             1|  0.0|2006-08-30 12:11:...|
|       2|             1|  0.0|2006-08-30 14:13:...|
|       2|             2|  0.0|2006-08-30 12:30:...|
|       2|             2|  0.0|2006-08-30 14:30:...|
|       2|             3|  0.0|2006-09-05 12:29:...|
|       2|             3|  0.0|2006-09-05 14:31:...|
|       3|             1|  0.0|2006-09-05 12:42:...|
|       3|             1|  0.0|2006-09-05 14:43:...|
+--------+--------------+-----+--------------------+
```

I know I can do this:

```py
df_data.where(col('bid')
       .isin([1,2,3])).show()
```

in order to select only the rows which have a `bid` of one of `[1,2,3]`.

However, I want to be able to select a subset based on a list of tuples `[(1,1), (2,2), (3,1)]` for the two columns `aid` and `bid`.

So basically "*something like*"

```py
df_data.where(col(['aid', 'bid'])
       .isin([(1,1), (2,2), (3,1)])).show()
```

Is there a way to do this?

I could imagine something like this:

```py
sql.sql('SELECT * FROM df_data WHERE (scope_id, measurement_id) IN ((1,1))')
```

but this will throw:

```python
AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '(struct(df_data.`aid`, df_data.`bid`) IN (struct(1, 1)))' due to data type mismatch: Arguments must be same type; line 1 pos 55"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of three ways.

#### Method 1: Use `reduce` to help check all conditions

The pseudocode `(s, m) IN [(1,1), (2,2), (3,1)]` is equivalent to:

```python
(s == 1 and m == 1) or (s == 2 and m == 2) or (s == 3 and m == 3)
```

You can check all of these conditions using a list comprehension and `reduce`.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
check_list = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,1)]
df.where(
        reduce(
            lambda u, v: u|v,
            [(f.col("aid") == x) & (f.col("bid") == y) for (x,y) in check_list]
        )
    )\
    .select("aid", "bid", "value")\
    .show()
#+---+---+-----+
#|aid|bid|value|
#+---+---+-----+
#|  1|  1| 81.0|
#|  1|  1| 81.0|
#|  2|  2|  0.0|
#|  2|  2|  0.0|
#|  3|  1|  0.0|
#|  3|  1|  0.0|
#+---+---+-----+
```

#### Method 2: Concatenate the IDs as strings

Create a temporary column as the string concatenation of the two `id` columns. Then check to see if that string matches a list of strings.

```python
check_list = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,1)]
check_list_str = [",".join([str(x) for x in item]) for item in check_list]

df.withColumn("combined_id", f.concat(f.col("aid"), f.lit(","), f.col("bid")))\
    .where(f.col("combined_id").isin(check_list_str))\
    .select("aid", "bid", "value")\
    .show()
#+---+---+-----+
#|aid|bid|value|
#+---+---+-----+
#|  1|  1| 81.0|
#|  1|  1| 81.0|
#|  2|  2|  0.0|
#|  2|  2|  0.0|
#|  3|  1|  0.0|
#|  3|  1|  0.0|
#+---+---+-----+
```

#### Method 3: Use a UDF

Create a `udf` to check the boolean condition.

```python
check_list = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,1)]
check_id_isin = f.udf(lambda x, y: (x, y) in check_list, BooleanType())

df.where(check_id_isin(f.col("aid"), f.col("bid")) == True)\
    .select("aid", "bid", "value")\
    .show()
#+---+---+-----+
#|aid|bid|value|
#+---+---+-----+
#|  1|  1| 81.0|
#|  1|  1| 81.0|
#|  2|  2|  0.0|
#|  2|  2|  0.0|
#|  3|  1|  0.0|
#|  3|  1|  0.0|
#+---+---+-----+
```

**EDIT** As @StefanFalk [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487869/how-to-select-rows-given-a-list-of-tuples-with-a-pyspark-dataframe/49493804#comment85991809_49493804), one could write the `udf` more generally as:

```python
check_id_isin = f.udf(lambda *idx: idx in check_list, BooleanType())
```

Which will allow for a variable number of input parameters.

Comment: Huh, somehow I still don't have `udf`s on my radar. I even think one could write `f.udf(lambda *tup: tup in check_list, BooleanType())` - which should allow a variable number of parameters for `check_id_isin`. At this point *Method 3* is my favorite :)

Comment: @StefanFalk yes, that would work too. I generally try to avoid `udf` because they're slower- but sometimes it's the only way to implement complicated functions. Check my updated method 1- I think that may work out to be the best.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be

```
>>> df.show()
+---+---+
|aid|bid|
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
|  1|  2|
|  1|  3|
|  2| 10|
|  2| 12|
+---+---+

>>> checkList = [(1,2),(2,12),(1,100)]
>>> df.rdd.filter(lambda x, y: (x,y) in checkList).toDF().show()
+---+---+
|aid|bid|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  2| 12|
+---+---+
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work, returning `'TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y''`